# Indexing issues with arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing, arduino

The code I have fills an array of size 5 with 5 different values (code not shown). It then populates each index in the array with a corresponding number (bottom function). It then saves the previous largest index (initially starts at 0). It then searches the array for the largest value, saves that value and the index at which it was found.

However when ever I run it multiple times it will never give me a current index value of 0. It is always at one. For example. First time I run it and the previous largest index is 0 and current index is 1 (which is correct). Then when I run it again, having the first value being the largest. The previous largest index will be 1 (correct), yet the current index value would also be 1. (Should be 0).

Can someone find out whats wrong with my code?

```
float highestTemperature(float temperaturearray[])
{
  int arraylength = 5; //knows how large the array is
  hottest = temperaturearray[0];
  previouslargestindex = currentlargestindex;
  Serial.print("previous largest index = ");
  Serial.println(previouslargestindex);

  for(int i = 0; i < arraylength; i++) //loops through the array 
  {
    if(temperaturearray[i] > hottest) 
    {
      hottest = temperaturearray[i]; 
     currentlargestindex = i;
    } //end if statement 
  } //end for loop
  Serial.print("current largest index = ");
  Serial.println(currentlargestindex);
}

float fillarray(float temperaturearray[])
{
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  temperaturearray[0] = sensors.getTempC(Probe01);
  temperaturearray[1] = sensors.getTempC(Probe02);
  temperaturearray[2] = sensors.getTempC(Probe03);
  temperaturearray[3] = sensors.getTempC(Probe04);
  temperaturearray[4] = sensors.getTempC(Probe05);
}
```

Comment: Try changing i++ to ++i not sure though

Comment: Both functions say they return a float but they actually return nothing.

Comment: [Minimal test-case](http://sscce.org) please.

Comment: Does `println` actually print `float`, or does it want a C-style string?  I suspect the latter.  Also, you need to initialize `currentlargestindex` to 0 before your loop that looks for the largest index, otherwise if the largest index is 0, it won't update the `currentlargestindex` properly.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `hottest` to a value smaller than any of the temperatures in the array.  The reason is that if the hottest temperature is in index 0 then `if(temperaturearray[i] > hottest)` won't be true when `i` is `0` and `currentlargestindex` won't be updated.

I recommend using `FLT_MIN` or `std::numeric_limits<float>::min()`, but any value you know will be smaller is fine.

You could also try `if(temperaturearray[i] >= hottest)` although floating point equality can be complicated.  If assigning the value as shown is all you do it should be fine.

Comment: The equal sign is what I was missing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No you weren't! You failed initializing as answer says!

Answer (score 0):

Your failure is initializing `currentlargestindex`.

As you did `hottest = temperaturearray[0];` you should also do `currentlargestindex=0;`.

However, your code can be much more improved:

```
float highestTemperature(float temperaturearray[]) {
  int arraylength = 5; //knows how large the array is
  int currentlargestindex = 0; //Assume first item is hottest one
  for(int i = 1; i < arraylength; i++) {//Don't need to check 0 again, check just 1, ...!
    if(temperaturearray[i] > temperaturearray[currentlargestindex]) {
      currentlargestindex = i; 
      //hottest=temperaturearray[i]; //Not needed, same as temperaturearray[currentlargestindex]
    }
  }
  //This is a float returning function, so return it!
  return temperaturearray[currentlargestindex];
}
```